# Try to Install GLFW on Steam Deck

Tags: cmake, glfw, steamos

i have a Steam Deck and would like to install GLFW on a Steamdeck, so that VSCode can find the Libary, i use Cmake. I used Cmake on another linux machine with no problems. I think its related to the steam deck and steam os.

I a location in with the following files in usr/lib/cmake/glfw3 :

- glfw3Targets.cmake,
- glfw3Targets-noconfig.cmake,
- glfw3ConfigVersion.cmak,
- glfw3Config.cmake

Also there are two header files in /usr/include/GLFW called:

- glfw3.h
- glfw3native.h

Also i have this so's:

- /usr/lib/libglfw.so
- /usr/lib/libglfw.so.3
- /usr/lib/libglfw.so.3.3

In the main.cpp file the #include <GLFW/glfw3.h> do not work.

My Cmake file looks now like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(test)

# Add executable
add_executable(test src/main.cpp)

# Specify the path to GLFW include directory
set(GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR "/usr/include" CACHE PATH "Path to GLFW include directory")

# Specify the path to GLFW library directory
set(GLFW_LIBRARY_DIR "/usr/lib" CACHE PATH "Path to GLFW library directory")

# Add GLFW include directory
target_include_directories(test PRIVATE ${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR})

# Link GLFW library to your executable
target_link_libraries(test ${GLFW_LIBRARY_DIR}/libglfw.so)
```

Maybe some one with a better understanding of cmake, c and linux can help me.

Thank you in advance.

I tried different combinations of cmake files with find() and so on. Looked into the internet, and used Chat GPT to find a solution.
Reinstalled with

```
sudo pacman -S glfw-x11
```

glfw again on the steam deck.

EDIT:

Here is the full error when i start the building:

```
[main] Building folder: game_engine all
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: /usr/bin/cmake --build /home/deck/Programming/game_engine/build --config Debug --target all --
[build] ninja: error: '/usr/lib/libglfw.so', needed by 'test', missing and no known rule to make it
[proc] The command: /usr/bin/cmake --build /home/deck/Programming/game_engine/build --config Debug --target all -- exited with code: 1
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:00.029
[build] Build finished with exit code 1
```

EDIT2:

When i safe the CMakeList.txt i get following message in VSCode:

```
[main] Configuring project: game_engine 
[proc] Executing command: /usr/bin/cmake --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/g++ -S/home/deck/Programming/game_engine -B/home/deck/Programming/game_engine/build -G Ninja
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- Configuring done (0.0s)
[cmake] -- Generating done (0.0s)
[cmake] -- Build files have been written to: /home/deck/Programming/game_engine/build
```

Permission of usr/lib/libglfw.so:

with following command: `ls -l libglfw.so`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Jul 23  2022 libglfw.so -> libglfw.so.3

EDIT3:

if i change my `target_link_libraries(test ${GLFW_LIBRARY_DIR}/libglfw.so)` to `target_link_libraries(test $usr/lib/libglfw.so.3.3)`

Permission is set to: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 278200 Jul 23  2022 /usr/lib/libglfw.so.3.3

Permission of /usr/include/GLFW/glfw3.h: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 215860 Jul 23  2022 glfw3.h

i get this error in the build process:

```
[main] Building folder: game_engine 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: /usr/bin/cmake --build /home/deck/Programming/game_engine/build --config Debug --target all --
[build] [1/2  50% :: 0.022] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test.dir/src/main.cpp.o
[build] FAILED: CMakeFiles/test.dir/src/main.cpp.o 
[build] /usr/bin/g++   -g -std=gnu++11 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/test.dir/src/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/test.dir/src/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/test.dir/src/main.cpp.o -c /home/deck/Programming/game_engine/src/main.cpp
[build] /home/deck/Programming/game_engine/src/main.cpp:3:10: fatal error: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory
[build]     3 | #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
[build]       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] compilation terminated.
[build] ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
[proc] The command: /usr/bin/cmake --build /home/deck/Programming/game_engine/build --config Debug --target all -- exited with code: 1
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:00.054
[build] Build finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: "the #include <GLFW/glfw3.h> do not work." - This is too vague description of the error. Instead, add to the question post the **exact error message**. (As a rule: if you need to ask help about the error, then you usually don't understand the error message. And if you don't understand the error message, then you don't know what part of the error message are important. In that case, attempt to *describe* the error "in a few words" has a high chance to miss important details.)

Comment: According to the error message, you actually do NOT have the file `/usr/lib/libglfw.so` which you use in `target_link_libraries` command. You may verify that by command `ls /usr/lib/libglfw.so`.

Comment: /usr/lib/libglfw.so is the response in the terminal

Comment: So i looked more around and it looks like the libglfw.so is a symbolic link to libglfw.so.3. Maybe this is the problem? @Tsyvarev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for my System.

1. Download GWFL Libary from https://www.glfw.org/
2. Place it on the level of to cmake file of your project.

Your Project would look like this:
GraficsProgramDirectory

-----src:

---------main.cpp

-----CMakeLists.txt

-----glfw-3.4

3. Inside the CMake File is the following:

```
     make_minimum_required( VERSION 3.5 )
    
    project( test )
    
    set(OpenGL_GL_PREFERENCE "GLVND")
    
    find_package( OpenGL REQUIRED )
    
    include_directories( ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
    
    set( GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL  "GLFW lib only" )
    set( GLFW_INSTALL OFF CACHE BOOL  "GLFW lib only" )
    set( GLAD_GL "" )
    
    add_subdirectory( glfw-3.4 )
    
    option( USE_GLAD "Use GLAD from GLFW" ON )
    
    if( USE_GLAD )
        include_directories("${GLFW_SOURCE_DIR}/deps")
        set( GLAD_GL "${GLFW_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/glad/gl.h" )
    endif()
    
    
    
    set( TEST_START
            src/main.cpp
            )
    
    add_executable( test  ${TEST_START} ${GLAD_GL} )
    target_link_libraries( test ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} glfw )
```

set(OpenGL_GL_PREFERENCE "GLVND") is only needed if cmake says it do find multiple OpenGL Libarys

4. Build your project.

I build this Solution with the Help of:
https://github.com/juliettef/GLFW-CMake-starter